# VueJS Module not found error while importing the components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have an app where I load component using `<router-view/>`!

I am getting the problem in importing the component in `router.js`. It always gives me the following error:

```
These relative modules were not found:

* ./components/Poetry.vue in ./src/router/routes.js
* ./components/PoetryDetails/PoetryCard.vue in ./src/router/routes.js
* ./components/PoetryDetails/Search.vue in ./src/router/routes.js
```

I have the folder structure like this:

```
├── _components
|   ├── _PoetryDetails
|   |   └──PoetryCard.vue
|   |   └──Search.vue
|   └── Poetry.vue
├── _router
|   ├── index.js (routes.js is imported in this file)
|   └── routes.js
├── App.vue
└── main.js
```

In `routes.js`, I am importing the components as follows:

```
import Poetry from './components/Poetry.vue'
import PoetryCard from './components/PoetryDetails/PoetryCard.vue'
import PoetrySearch from './components/PoetryDetails/Search.vue'

export const routes = [
    { path: '', name: 'poetrysearch', component: Poetry, children: [
        { path: 'poetry', name: 'poetrycard', component: PoetryCard },
        { path: 'poetry/search', name: 'poetrysearch', component: PoetrySearch },
    ]},
]
```

But, I am still getting the damn error. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using relative path. In your `routes.js`, it should be

```
import Poetry from '../components/Poetry.vue'
import PoetryCard from '../components/PoetryDetails/PoetryCard.vue'
import PoetrySearch from '../components/PoetryDetails/Search.vue'
```

`..` notation means go to parent folder.

If you're using webpack, you can add alias:

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      ...
      '@': resolve('src'), // your source folder
    }
  }
```

and then you can import:

```
import Poetry from '@/components/Poetry.vue'
import PoetryCard from '@/components/PoetryDetails/PoetryCard.vue'
import PoetrySearch from '@/components/PoetryDetails/Search.vue'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am still getting this error: `* ../main in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/PoetryDetails/Search.vue, ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/PoetryDetails/PoetryCard.vue`

Comment: Actually, these components were first in `/components` and then I created a new folder and moved these components(`PoetryCard.vue` and `Search.vue`) in that folder. And since then, I am getting this annoying error.

Comment: Found the error. Actually, I did some import in those files too so I needed to make changes there too and thanks for that `@`!